# iteration calculation based on another dataframe

Tags: pandas, function, iteration

How to do iteration calculation as shown in df2 as desired output ?

any reference links for this > many thanks for helping

df1

```
   a  b  c
0  1  0  5
1  9  9  2
2  2  2  8
3  6  3  0
4  6  1  7
```

df2 :

```
   a   b   c
0  1   0   5  >> values from df1
1  19  18  9  >> values from (df1.iloc[1] * 2) + df2.iloc[0] *1)
2  23  22  25 >> values from (df1.iloc[2] * 2) + df2.iloc[1] *1)
3  35  28  25 >> values from (df1.iloc[3] * 2) + df2.iloc[2] *1)
4  47  30  39 >> values from (df1.iloc[4] * 2) + df2.iloc[3] *1)
```

---

here is my previous way:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
df2.iloc[0] = df1.iloc[:1]
size = len(df1.index)

for i in range(1,size):
    df2.values[i] = ((df1.values[i] * 2) +  (df2.values[i-1] * 3))
```

Comment: Can you break down the `23`?

Comment: Hi mozway, do you mean the calculation 23 ? (2 * 2) + (19 * 1)

Comment: OK, so `(2*2)+(9*2)+(1*2)-1` = `(2+9+1)*2-1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df2 = df1.mul(2).cumsum().sub(df1.iloc[0])
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   0   5
1  19  18   9
2  23  22  25
3  35  28  25
4  47  30  39
```

##### more complex operation

If you want `x[n] = x[n]*2 + x[n-1]*2`, you need to iterate:

```
def process(s):
    out = [s[0]]
    for x in s[1:]:
        out.append(x*2+out[-1]*3)
    return out

df1.apply(process)
```

Output:

```
     a    b    c
0    1    0    5
1   21   18   19
2   67   58   73
3  213  180  219
4  651  542  671
```